# Failed installation preventing TFS install

Tags: tfs, windows-installer

I have been having problems installing programs for a while, Usually getting an error that Visual Studio j# install is an unfinished install and it gives me an option to rollback that install before installing the program I am trying to install.

I am now trying to install Team Foundation Server 2012 Express and when I run the installer I get the following error.

Error : TF400293 : Windows is currently installing another package.  Wait until Windows finishes the other installation, and then restart this setup program.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to get rid of the failed installation once and for all so I can install other stuff without all these problems.

Im using windows 7 by the way.

Also I seem to be unable to fully complete a Windows Update. It seems like there is 1 update that will never install and my computer just hangs on the installing update screen. I left it for 4+ hours once and decided it would not complete so had to just turn off my computer.

Comment: While it is a development product you're trying to install, I suspect you'll have better luck asking this question at SuperUser...

Comment: @DanPuzey: http://stackoverflow.com/tour explicitly lists "Software development tools" as on-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @JoeyAdams: While I can't be sure, since I posted the comment 20 months ago, I'm pretty sure that my comment a) explicitly recognizes that the question is about a software development tool, and b) doesn't suggest that the question is offtopic. All I said was that I thought the OP might have better luck at SuperUser, because this general class of question tends to find its answers there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got this error message when a setup failed but the MSIEXEC.exe is still running or when there's a restart pending blocking other installation.

For the first case: kill the MSIEXE.exe process.

For the second: Use regedit to look at this key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations` Clear out any value in the key and then try again.

This issue is not TFS related, by the way.

Comment: Yes I gathered its due to a previous failed installation. Disabled the MSI service restarted and installed MSI SDK where there is atool called MSIZAP.exe This has enabled me to at least begin the installation of TFS.

Comment: Beware, the MSI Windows Service is different from the MSIEXE.Exe (which is launched by the Windows Service when you launch a .msi file) which is a process run to install a given software. You can have multiple instances of MSIEXE.exe for instance.

Comment: Killing the MSIEXEC.exe process worked but is there a way I can stop it automatically restarting installs all the time?

Comment: To whoever voted this answer down... please can you at least comment on WHY you voted it down? Im assuming because you dissagree with the information provided?

Comment: I honestly don't know why some one voted it down and didn't explain, this is not a good community effort.. but you can still mark the answer as the best one! ;) If the MSIEXEC restart each time, look for these keys in regedit.exe HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\PnpResources\Registry\HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce maybe the installer is still referenced.